# Тестирование deep link

Tags: android, kotlin, adb, deeplink

Пытаюсь протестировать открытие приложения по deeplink'у
Если вбивать в терминале:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "deeplink"
```

То все будет открываться
Но если я это делаю в тесте через метод:

```
fun openAppByDeepLink(link: String) {
        executeShellCommand("am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d '$link'")
}
```

То почему то ничего не работает и в логах ошибка `No value for deep_link`
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно открывать deeplink из теста на kotlin

Comment: Тут пишут что интентами: https://www.mobot.io/blog/how-to-test-deep-links-in-android